# $_POST [] array is empty after submission

Tags: php, phpstorm-10

So $_POST['acc'], and $_POST['psw'] can't get data from the form for some reason, they are empty all the time.

html:

```
<div id="signUp_UI">
    <form id="su_form" action="<?php echo url_for('/sign_up.php')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        YYQ<br><br>
        Account Name<br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Account Name" id="an" name="acc">
        <br><br>
        Passward<br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="psw">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" name="goback" value="Go Back" id="gb_button">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="su_button2">
    </form>
</div>
```

php:

```
$an = isset($_POST['acc']) ? $_POST['acc'] : '';
$psw = isset($_POST['psw']) ? $_POST['psw'] : '';

$sql = "INSERT INTO log_in (account, password) VALUES ('". $an . "'," . "'" . $psw . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if($result){
    $new_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    redirect_to(url_for('/home.php?id=') . $new_id);
}
else{
    echo mysqli_error($db);
    db_disconnect($db);
    exit();
}
```

Update:

So if I change php code to:

```
if(is_post_request()){

$an = isset($_POST['acc']) ? $_POST['acc'] : '';
$psw = isset($_POST['psw']) ? $_POST['psw'] : '';


$sql = "INSERT INTO log_in (account, password) VALUES ('". h($an) . "'," . "'" . h($psw) . "');";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if($result){
    echo '$an = ' . $an .'<br>';
    echo '$psw = ' . $psw;
}
else{
    echo mysqli_error($db);
    db_disconnect($db);
    exit();
}
```

then I got the result:
$an = 
$psw =

UPDATE:

So I tried to detect `isset($_POST['submit'])` in php file, the result is $_POST['submit'] does not exist.

So it's like after I've submit the form, it isn't been sent to the php file for some reason.

UPDATE 3.0:

So if i change method to get, everything works find! I don't know why is that.

html:

```
<div id="signUp_UI">
    <form id="su_form" action="<?php echo url_for('/sign_up.php'); ?>" method="get">
        YYQ GameStation<br><br>
        Account Name<br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Account Name" id="an" name="account">
        <br><br>
        Password<br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" name="goback" value="Go Back" id="gb_button">
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Sign Up" id="su_button2">
    </form>
</div>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && !empty($_GET['submit'])){
$an = isset($_GET['account'])?$_GET['account']:'';
$psw = isset($_GET['password'])?$_GET['password']:'';

$sql = "INSERT INTO log_in (account, password) VALUES ('". h($an) . "'," . "'" . h($psw) . "');";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if($result){
    redirect_to(url_for('/home.php'));
}
else{
    echo mysqli_error($db);
    db_disconnect($db);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form?

Comment: remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @nogad shouldn't make a difference in this case

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plaintext!**

Comment: Share what value you are getting in action?

Comment: Do you have any javascript to validate and submit the form? Try including this line: **var_dump($_POST);** in your script, before any other action. And **do not include any user input data directly into your SQL statements**.

Comment: eliminating the unnecessary increases the change of success.

Comment: I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to send "account" and "password" information from the form to mysql db, but in the table "log_in", account and password for the row are empty. It seems like what I typed didn't sent to $_POST[ ] array at all.

Comment: @user2486  so $an and $psw are empty since i set isset($_POST['acc']) ? $_POST['acc'] : '';

Comment: @KevinYang : what value you are getting here `url_for('/sign_up.php')` ?

Comment: Also you should reply on all comments above

Comment: @user248 so url_for('/sign_up.php')  is where the sign_up php file is.

Comment: @Phil  So I'm trying to send "account" and "password" information from the form to mysql db, but in the table "log_in", account and password for the row are empty. It seems like what I typed didn't sent to $_POST[ ] array at all.

Comment: @KevinYang Comment you need to reply to if you want any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170718/post-array-is-empty-after-submission#comment81291068_47170718

Comment: @KevinYang How about you also tag the framework you're using; this is clearly not just php.

Comment: Where does `is_post_request()` come from? You also haven't answered my question... are you entering data into the form and hitting the submit button?

Comment: @Phil  so I created the function is_post_request() to check weather the request method is POST or not.
and yes, I hope I could enter "account" and "password" information from form and store them into database.

Comment: When  you **var_dump($_POST);** what is the result?

Comment: ... while you're there, add in `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);` too and post the results

Comment: @Bluetree so the result for var_dump($_POST) is array(0) { }

Comment: @Phil the result for var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']); is string(4) "POST"

Comment: Do you have javascript that validates your username and password?
Can you also try to inspect element this `<form id="su_form" action="<?php echo url_for('/sign_up.php'); ?>" method="get">`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, according to sources I've found, it seems that there is something wrong with phpstrom build-in server. POST method somehow just doesn't work.

Reference ~ https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125-PhPStorm-10-does-not-allow-POST-method

Comment: You'll need a comparison to verify this. Try using PHP's [built-in HTTP server](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: This problem is fixed after upgraded phpstorm to latest version.

Answer (score -2):

Why you need to do this?

```
<form id="su_form" action="<?php echo url_for('/sign_up.php')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Can you try to replace this

from:

```
action="<?php echo url_for('/sign_up.php')?>"
```

to:

```
action="sign_up.php"
```

Comment: I know it's not necessary, but basically they do the same thing in this case.

Comment: try to alert($_POST['acc'].$_POST['psw']) to sign_up.php. Show us the exact output.

Comment: @Zach `alert` is a JS function

Comment: @Zach so I got the result:
$an = 
$psw =